# Regex para ignorar nomes de arquivos inválidos

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, yaml

Olá, estou tentando adicionar uma regex no `app.yaml` para ignorar arquivos com nomes estranhos no *Google App Engine*, mas não esta funcionando.

Minha expressão regular:

```
skip_files:
- [.\\~#%&*{}:<>?|\"-!]
```

Estou recebendo este erro:

> appcfg.py: error: Error parsing /home/klarkc/project/dist/app.yaml:
>   while scanning for the next token found character '|' that cannot
>   start any token   in "/home/klarkc/project/dist/app.yaml", line 49,
>   column 18.

Comment: Você precisa de uma expressão que ignore os caracteres: `.\~#%&*{}:<>?|"-!`, certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, que funcione no yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A expressão abaixo permite que case apenas os carácteres alfabéticos letras de `A..Z` e `a..z` e números `0..9` e os símbolos `-`, `_`, `.` e o espaço em branco  , veja.

Expressão:

```
^[\w\-. ]+$
```

Para faze o inverso e permitir que cases apenas os símbolos especiais `*&%#^~` basta usar a lista negada `^`, veja abaixo:

Expressão:

```
^[^\w\-. ]+$
```

Fonte: [Regular expression for valid filename.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794507/5429980)

Comment: Teria como negar essa expressão? Já que o parâmetro é para filtrar os arquivos que serão ignorados e não os que arquivos a serem aprovados.

Comment: Apesar da outra solução do @Gomiero ter funcionado, no final das contas acabei usando a sua solução, porque filtra tudo que não é válido, em vez de procurar por caracteres específicos. A única mudança que eu fiz foi usar a regex assim: ^.*[^\w\-.\s\/]+.*$ para adicionar também o separador de diretório à lista de caracteres aceitos e .* pra dar match em caracteres anteriores e posteriores respectivamente.

Comment: @WalkerLeite você fez uma edição que alterou coisas substanciais na resposta, por isso foi rejeitada. Quando quiser sugerir alterações substanciais que possam alterar o sentido da pergunta/resposta, notifique o autor sobre as mudanças e peça que ele mesmo faça.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa escapar alguns caracteres, veja abaixo como deve ser sua regex;

`[\.\\~#%&\*\{\}\:<>\?\|\-!]`

na sua original faltou escapar o

- `.` -> Equivale por qualquer caractere
- `{}` -> para informar uma quantidade de repetidores ex `.{4}`
- `:`-> Não sei a funcionalidade, "alguém edita"
- `?` -> significa que tem que terminar assim a expressao
- `|` -> Operador OU
- `-` -> usado para grupos, tipo `0-9`

Answer (score 1):

A expresssão abaixo, encontra os nomes arquivos com os caracteres da lista `.\~#%&*{}:<>?|"-!:`:

`^[^\\\#\%\&\*\{\}\:\<\>\?\|\"\-\!]+$`

[Veja um caso de uso funcionando no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jO5cZ4/1)

`^`  match no início da linha

`+`  uma ou mais vezes

`$`  match no final da linha

Mais exemplos (talvez melhores) em: 
[Skipping Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files).

Para validar a sintaxe dos arquivos [YAML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) (antes de utilizá-los):

[Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

[Code Beautify - YAML Validator](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator)

[YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/)